# Manually register a Spring @Configuration class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-autoconfiguration

I have a Spring `@Configuration` class which creates a bunch of Spring Beans and has few Spring Data Annotations. Is there a way for me to not add the `@Configuration` Annotation so that Spring does not pick it automatically and instead I can add it programmatically?

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.mypackages",
       entityManagerFactoryRef = "myEntityManagerFactory,
        transactionManagerRef = "myTransactionManager")
public class DBConfig {

    @Bean("myDatasource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myconfig.datasource")
    public DataSource myDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                // Set other configs
                .build();
    }

    @Bean("myEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
    myEntityManagerFactory(@Qualifier("myDatasource") DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lb = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lb.setPackagesToScan("com.mypackages");
        // Set other configs
        return lb;
    }

    @Bean("myTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager myTransactionManager(@Qualifier("myEntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        // Set other configs
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }

}
```

I want to remove the `@Configuration` annotation from `DBConfig` class so that Spring does not create these beans automatically all the time during startup. Instead I want another bean to check a config that it loads from another source (Dynamo in this case) and initialize this class if required.

```java
@Service
public class MyConfigLoader {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private DynamoDbClient dynamoDbClient;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        Map<String, Boolean> configs = dynamoDbClient.getConfigs();
        boolean initializeDb = configs.get("dbRequired");
        if(initializeDb){
            // Something like this
            context.registerConfigurationClass(DBConfig.class);
        }

    }

}
```

The usual way is to set a property and use `@ConditionalOnProperty` to pick up the Configuration class, but this will not work here as the flags are to be read from Dynamo during startup.

Is this possible?
Does something like `context.registerConfigurationClass(DBConfig.class)` exist?
And the Annotations like `@EnableTransactionManagement` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` should also work.

Comment: And why wouldn't that work. Make the things that are read from dynamo part of the environment as a propertysource (as that is what you are using it for apparently). That way it will work with regular constructs instead of trying to shoehorn something new into it.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have just provided a simplified code snippet of what the dynamo data is being used for. It will be difficult to explain it fully but the Dynamo Config is used to build Dynamic Camel Routes which integrates with various sources and targets. So the Dynamo Config is not a map that can be used as a property source but has a lot of nested configs which are not really supposed to be injected as spring properties.

Comment: The joys of asking a question with dumbed down code (please don't). Nonetheless you can still expose it (or at least some properties) as property source and use all the general available features. That way you know it will work, shoehorning something else it will eventually end up breaking (as things will change in between versions). I would also argue that it might even make your camel route registration easier (but that is just without seeing and knowing what you are doing).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it for this use case, but consider implementing `EnvironmentPostProcessor` that will connect to dynamo db and read the necessary properties, and based on the values in the database it will programmatically create a "business oriented property map property source" and define a property that later can be used as a condition for your `DbConfig` configuration:

Something like this:

```java
package org.mypackage;
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class DataBaseAvailabilityResolvingEnvPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, 
      SpringApplication application) {
        // connect to Dynamo Db, use environment to read connection string, credentials, etc.
        // resolve the values from the dynamo db and based on those:

        environment.getPropertySources()
          .addAfter(SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME, new MapPropertySource(...)); // add property named "mydb.enabled" with value true or false 
    }
}
```

Now you can register it in `META-INF/spring.factories` as usual:

```
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=
  org.mypackage.DataBaseAvailabilityResolvingEnvPostProcessor
```

So spring run trigger this code even before it comes `@Configuration` annotated classes processing.

Now on your configuration class you can use `@ConditionalOnProperty`, like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.mypackages",
       entityManagerFactoryRef = "myEntityManagerFactory,
        transactionManagerRef = "myTransactionManager")
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "mydb.enabled", havingValue = true) // I've added this line
public class DBConfig {
...
}
```

Another (although really similar option) is instead of creating a `MappedPropertySource` in the environment post processor class, register an "artificial" profile (you can add profiles dynamically). In this case, the configuration class will rely on the presence of the profile.